# Not able to insert an email in PayPal Sandbox with selenium

Tags: selenium, paypal

I enter to the paypal sandbox.
Email field:
find the element is ok.
When I trying to insert text to it by sendkeys - a msg that the element is not visible is displayed.
I add the "visibilityOfElementLocated" - now the following msg is displayed :

```
TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //*[@id='email'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
```

Code block :

```
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']")));
email.sendKeys("abc@abc.com");
```

**Error trace:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //input[@id='email'] (tried for 500 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'LIBI-PC', ip: '192.168.9.102', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f), userDataDir=C:\Users\libi\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7328_16382}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=63.0.3239.84, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: c7444970bdc7c79175dd5c98d31d7ee7
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:232)
    at LEOlaneTestCases.payPal.testllll(payPal.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Can you try to increase timeout time.

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);  - here?

Comment: Yes chnage it to 30 Sec

Comment: I changed it to more and with no change...

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to `sendKeys()` to the **Email** field of `Pay Pal Sandbox` you need to use `ExpectedConditions` with clause as **`elementToBeClickable`** identifying the **Email** field through an unique `xpath` as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']"))).sendKeys("abc@abc.com");
```

Comment: I received this timeout msg again.

Comment: @libi Can you get me the complete error stack trace please. With Selenium 3.8.1, Gecko 0.19.1 & Firefox Quantum I don't require any wait as such.

Comment: It is too long to the comment box. What do you need exactly?

Comment: @libi Not in the comment box. Edit the Question and add the current code block & error stack trace as an update.

Comment: Done, you can see it.

Comment: Did you try my line of code? What error do you se when you try my line of code instead of yours?

Comment: Selenium version please? I think you got `chromedriver=2.33.x` and `Chrome=63.0`

Comment: Did you add `import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;` and `import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;` ?